# store values and continue running function

Tags: python, astropy

I am using astropy to detect sources in an image. I am trying to write a function that will detect my sources, with an option of storing their coordinates in an array, and another option to plot the sources. This is my code:

```
def SourceDetect(file, SIG, FWHM, THRESH, store = False, PlotStars = False):
    image = pf.open(file)
    im = image[0].data
    mean, median, std = sigma_clipped_stats(im, sigma=SIG)
    daofind = DAOStarFinder(fwhm = FWHM, threshold = THRESH * std) 
    sources = daofind(im - median)
    positions = np.transpose((sources['xcentroid'], sources['ycentroid']))
    if(store):
        return positions
    if(PlotStars):
        apertures = CircularAperture(positions, r = 6.) 
        norm = ImageNormalize(stretch = SqrtStretch())
        plt.imshow(im, cmap = 'Greys', origin = 'lower', norm = norm, 
        interpolation = 'nearest')
        apertures.plot(color = 'blue', lw = 1.5, alpha = 1)
        for i in range(0, len(sources)):
            plt.text(sources[i]['xcentroid'], sources[i]['ycentroid'], i, color='black');
```

However when I run this code with both store and plot set to True only the store part of the function runs and I can't get it to plot unless I make store False. Is there a way to write this code where I will be able to have my coordinates stored and plotted?

Comment: `return` exits function at once. Maybe you should put `if(PlotStars):` before `if(store):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple change order  - first `PlotStars`, next `store`

```
    if PlotStars:
        # ... code ...
    if store:
        return positions
```

and this will first display plot and later it exits function with value.

But if you want first get value and later plot then you should run it two times - first only with `store=True` and later only with `PlotStars=True`